# VBA: Use an array as a key in a dictionary object?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, object

I am working in Excel VBA (Excel 2013, x64) and trying to make a dictionary with arrays as keys. I currently have the following code, which I want to output "a,b" when called:

```
Sub DI()
Dim D As Object
Dim x As Variant
x = Array("a", "b")
'commenting out the line above and uncommenting the line below results in the output "a,b"
'x = "c"
Set D = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
D.Add x, "a,b"
Debug.Print D(x)
End Sub
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: A key of an array is a `String`. No options there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array cannot be used as a key of a dictionary, because the key should be a `String` type. Anyway, the array could be casted to string with the `Join(array, deliminator)` and used the casted string can be used as a key:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myDictionary As Object
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant

    x = Join(Array("a", "b"), ",")
    y = Join(Array("c", "d"), ",")
    
    Set myDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    myDictionary.Add x, "a,b"
    myDictionary.Add y, "c"
    
    Debug.Print myDictionary(x)
    Debug.Print myDictionary(y)

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the next way, please. **The key must be a string**, but the item can be an array:

```
Sub DI()
 Dim D As Object
 Dim x As Variant
 x = Array("a", "b")

 Set D = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 'The first array element can be a key:
 D.Add x(0), x
 Debug.Print D(x(0))(0), D(x(0))(1)
```