# Excel VBA Read and Write Back Table Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issues with reading data from an Excel table using VBA using an array variant, manipulating some of the data in the array variant and then writing the data back to the same Excel table.

Here is my code with 3 different ways of writing the data back.

```
Sub ReadModifyWrite()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim s As New stopwatch

Dim a As Variant: a = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange

a = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange 'Reading the data

For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1) 'gets the rows
    For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
        a(i, j) = "i:" & i & ",j:" & j & IIf(j > 1, " Random:" & Rnd(1), "") 'Manipulating the data
    Next j
Next i

s.start
Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange = a
Debug.Print "Sheet1.ListObjects(Table1).DataBodyRange = a: " & s.Elapsed_sec(3)

s.start
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 1).Address).Value = a
Debug.Print "Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.ListObjects(Table1).DataBodyRange(1, 1).Address).Value = a " & s.Elapsed_sec(3)

s.start
For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
    For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
        Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, j) = a(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
Debug.Print "i,j: " & s.Elapsed_sec(3)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Stopwatch module is from [here](https://github.com/hubisan/excel-vba-stopwatch.cls).

The timing results of each method are as follows with 1000 rows and 6 columns (my actual data could be larger). So I would prefer to stick with the first or second method below.

- `Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange` = a: 0.006
- `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 1).Address).Value` = a 0.002
- `i,j`: 0.756

With the first 2 methods, I am seeing the following issues when the data is "filtered" or "hidden".
[image]

Here is the immediate window for these 2 records.
[image]

[image]

The `i,j` method writes back to the Excel table without any issues, but takes much longer.

I also tried to show the columns with `Sheet1.Columns.AutoFit` but that produces additional issues.

Any insight on what the issue is with my code? Any idea how I can write the data back to the spreadsheet without removing the filters? Sure, I could use the `i,j` method, but the performance is not great when an end user is working on this spreadsheet.

Comment: Filtered data creates non-contiguous ranges. To read from / write to a non-contiguous range's `.Value`, loop over its `Areas`.

Comment: Why write to a variable and copy back to the table? Why not write directly to the table? Also, if you're manipulating data, the data you change may affect what is filtered. Why not remember the filter, turn it off, make the changes to the table in place, and reapply the filter?

Comment: Why don't you mix [Dictionary with arrays (sort of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540576/vba-use-an-array-as-a-key-in-a-dictionary-object)?

Comment: @BigBen, with my data filtered, I tried `Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Areas.Count` to see how many areas that I have and the results returned `1`. Does that seem right?

Comment: @StoneGiant, modifying the data directly in the table (sheet) produces very poor performance. I will look into reading the filter, clearing it, writing the data back and then applying the filter. But you are right, the filter could change based on the data manipulated.

Comment: @Sgdva, I looked but I do not understand how that applies to this issue that I am having.

Comment: @JoeFletch, sorry I should have specified I'm referring to the visible cells, and I assumed those are what you care about. If not, disregard.

Comment: If I understand correctly, i means the row you are in, you may save the properties that you care for in an array of it and access the dict later (dic(i)="Visible;j;random) so if the key is Visble then ... else etc.

Comment: About `3 different ways` test, the 2nd way only updates A cell. That's the reason why it takes less time than the 1st way. `DataBodyRange(1, 1)` is equalient to `DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)`.

Comment: @taller, thank you for pointing that out. I have changed the code and the issue still persists.

Comment: VBA just can't write an array to non-contiguous ranges all at once. You have to found a work around solution.